# How to retrieve Device-id/Token-id from android device [ Cordova + jquery ]

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, cordova-plugins

I have successfully build android app with cordova and jquery.
Now I want to start its push notification part, which I am doing with the help of `cordova-plugin-firebase`. But to send a notification to a particular device I need its token id or device id and to get that I am using a code.

```
window.FirebasePlugin.getToken(function(token) {
   // save this server-side and use it to push notifications to this device
        console.log(token);
    }, function(error) {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

I tried lot of thinks doesn't work for me, I couldn't retrieve token id.
Can anybody tell me how to retrieve token id from device in cordova.

And after getting a token id how to save this to firebase or should i save this to my server and if i do that, then how to link that saved data (on my server) to firebase.

Comment: is exist another solution but without firebase

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Can you explain your solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the plugin OneSignal it's Free

To add the plugin to your project  : **cordova plugin add onesignal-cordova-plugin**
[Official Website](https://onesignal.com/)

1. Add **index.js** to your project and Include in **index.html** like this

   ```
   var app = {
       initialize: function() {        
   document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
       window.plugins.OneSignal.enableNotificationsWhenActive(true);

     var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
       console.log('notificationOpenedCallback: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
     };

     window.plugins.OneSignal
       .startInit("Here add your id Go to your dashboard in onesignal")
       .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
       .endInit();
   }, false);

           this.bindEvents();
       },

       bindEvents: function() {
           document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
       },

       onDeviceReady: function() {
           app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
       },
       receivedEvent: function(id) {
           var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
           var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
           var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

           listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
           receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

           console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
       }
   };
   ```
2. **Step Two :**

   Go to dashboard => All users : here you fin all the users with device id - Name device - Platform - last session
3. **Step three:**

   You can send spesific message to users by id device or for all users

> read this document fo more information if you want to get player id and save in you basedonner ... : [click here](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/docs/product-overview)